# Error: Facing issue in starting my react server using command npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to start my react server but unable to do so because of this error below:

[image]

How do I resolve this error

Comment: Try moving the project into another category that the parent folders' name don't have a hashtag `#`.

Comment: thank you so much. It resolved this error